# Airline transfers EC261 compensation in different currency to EUR account, refuses to cover conversion fees

Tags: compensation, fees-and-charges, ec261

I submitted a claim for 400EUR compensation due to a cancelled flight under EU 261/2004 regulation from Aer Lingus and provided them with an EUR account in my home country (not Ireland, but in EU and part of SEPA). I was quite surprised when the amount I received was less than 400EUR. After some back and forth, they said my bank allegedly refused their initial EUR transfer so they converted the 400EUR to my local currency and sent that to the account I provided. Needless to say, I lost about 5% due to their unauthorized conversion to my local currency and from the currency of the transfer back to EUR by my bank.

The airline says they consider the matter closed because they transferred the compensation already. I am still 5% short of what I should have received and they never explained why they decided to do the above conversion without asking me first.

It seems obvious to me that they should have made a SEPA transfer and, when that failed, contacted me before doing anything else, but maybe I'm missing something and this is all within law? I note that the [EC 261/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32004R0261) regulation explicitly mentions the amount of compensation in EUR and doesn't have any provisions for alternative currencies in Article 7.1.

I realize it's not worth fighting this in court, but do I have any options to get the full amount?

Comment: I would have thought you need to clarify with your bank first.

Comment: I totally would've fought this in court since the original amount AND your account (!) is in EUR and you did NOT authorise a non-EUR transfer. For this, by all means try to find out from your bank what went wrong. A free-of-charge but slow option is https://secure.aviationreg.ie/eseries/uiid499108820/car450.xsp;jsessionid=16219ABE0F8553D7846106EDDCB2EF73.node1

Comment: I have asked my bank if they have a record of rejected transfers and if yes, the reason for rejection. I'll update the question with their response as soon as I receive it.
@Crazydre that link seems to require a login and a password and I can't find a way to register.

Comment: @Rathann Go to https://www.iaa.ie/consumer-protection/air-passenger-rights (then press "Complaint forms" at the bottom